# .htaccess code questions about SSL and canonicalization

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, canonicalization

In short, my website has a single payments page. SSL certificate is installed but is not required apart for that one payments page.

With regards to my `.htaccess` file - I currently separate my payments page with the following code. I also block visitors from `semalt.com`. Can't remember exactly why, but I think I was receiving unwanted attention (spam) from them at the time.

What I would like to know is:

1. is this code still valid 5 years on?
2. do I need to address canonicalization by directing to either a www or non-www version of mywebsite (importantly without affecting that one important https payments page); is it necessary?

```
 1. Options +FollowSymlinks
 2. RewriteEngine On
 3. RewriteBase /
 4. # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
 5. # RewriteRule .* http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 6. 
 7. RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 8. RewriteRule ^payment\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 9. 
 10. # block visitors referred from semalt.com
 11. RewriteEngine on
 12. RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
 13. RewriteRule .* – [F]
 14. # End semalt block
 15. # block referer spam buttons for website
 16. RewriteEngine On
 17. RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons\-for\-website\.com
 18. RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
 19. # End buttons for website block
 20. 
 21. ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing I would address is that you are only redirecting to HTTPS for your *payments page*. You should be forcing HTTPS for your entire site - everywhere. These days browsers alert users to the fact that they are browsing an insecure connection if on HTTP (Google Chrome states "Not Secure" next to the URL), which doesn't do anything for user trust. This is the main thing that would have changed in the last 5 years - HTTPS is mandatory *everywhere*.

There is no good reason *not* to use HTTPS everywhere these days.

Assuming the rest of your site is already HTTPS "ready" (I assume it must be and you aren't sending users back to HTTP from your payment page?!) then change the HTTP to HTTPS redirect to include your entire site:

```
# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

> 2) do I need to address canonicalization by directing to either a www or non-www version of mywebsite (importantly without affecting that one important https payments page); is it necessary?

Yes, you should. You already have the directives at the top of your `.htaccess` file - but they are commented out? You may have already set the `rel="canonical"` element in the head of your pages, but otherwise, if www and non-www are both available then this is potentially *duplicate content* (same content available from 2 or more different URLs). You need to decide which: www or non-www? Which do you currently favour? Which (predominantly) is already indexed? Which does your payments page use? (Hopefully, the answer is the same to all the above.)

Also redirect directly to HTTPS as part of this redirect. And this should go *before* the current HTTP to HTTPS redirect (the same order as currently in your `.htaccess` file):

```
# Redirect to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the above www to non-www redirect assumes you are not using any other subdomains. To redirect to `www.example.com`, just change both instances of `example.com`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule .* – [F]
> ```

Ok, if it helps - check your server logs if this is doing anything for you. But change the `.*` regex to `^` (marginally more efficient). And any blocking directives should be at the very top of the file (you don't want to bother canonicalising these requests).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons\-for\-website\.com
> RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
> ```

Again - OK, it helps (does it?!). Optimise the regex as above. No need to backslash escape literal hyphens in the *CondPattern* (unless they appear in the middle of a character class). The `L` flag is not required when used with `F`.

Other notes:

- No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive.
- You do not need the `RewriteBase /` directive with your current directives.
- It's clearer to define your `ErrorDocument`s at the top of the file.

#### Summary

Bringing the above points together we have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteEngine On

# block visitors referred from semalt.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ – [F]

# block referer spam buttons for website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Redirect to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I did not have the rel="canonical" element on all of my pages; but I do now.

Is it okay to show a complete site as https when only one page is used for secure purposes, such as a payments page?

Comment: Yes, of course. Not only is it "okay", it is much much better to do so. In fact, I would go so far to say that is is _mandatory_ these days - particularly since the browser actively "warns" the user that they are browsing an insecure site. Google Chrome browser states "Not Secure" next to the URL on any page that is served over plain HTTP. Presumably you aren't actively sending users back to HTTP after they have visited your payments page?

Comment: Ordinarily, data (sessions, cookies, authentication tokens, shopping carts, etc.) are shared between the payment page(s) and the rest of the site. Is your "payments page" working in total isolation and not leaking any information? (Cookies need to be HTTPS-only etc.) At the end of the day... do you have any reason _not_ to use HTTPS in other parts of the site?

Comment: "I did not have the rel="canonical" element on all of my pages; but I do now." - Is the site in question the one linked in your profile? As you appear to have set the canonical URL incorrectly and appended a trailing slash (which just results in an unstyled 404 page - due to the use of _relative_ URLs to static resources).

Comment: Yes, it is the same site as in my profile. I researched the usage of rel=canonical and all the examples I found showed the trailing slash. I bow to your knowledge and have changed to the following format on all of my pages: `code` <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" /> `code`

Comment: I can't work out how to make that into code, sorry.

Comment: I suspect my payments page is leaking information; but I can't work out why. I have the padlock, but also get a blocked content message.

Comment: You should use whatever is **your** canonical URL in the `rel="canonical"` link element - only you know what that should be (it's basically the URL that you would normally link to and the URL that you want search engines to index). (Appending a slash to the **end of the URL-path** completely changes the URL.)

Comment: Although, having said that, the document root URL, ie. `https://example.com/`, should strictly end in a slash. This slash is at the **start of the URL-path** (not the end) - it's not strictly valid without it - although all user-agents/browsers implicitly append a slash here (if omitted) to make a valid request, so it probably doesn't matter. See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/35646/1243) to [this Webmasters question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser) for more info on this.

Comment: A "blocked content message" would imply you are referencing a resource (image, CSS, JS, etc.) over HTTP when you are on a HTTPS URL, although I've not seen a "blocked content" warning when casually browsing your site. (?)